GCP Cloud Run service is allowed to read a bucket without permissions
I have a GCP Cloud Run service that needs to be read from a bucket. The service runs with its dedicated service account.
I see that the service can read the bucket without any explicitly given permissions/roles to do so, such as storage.objects.list/roles/storage.objectViewer.
Strangely, if I run the service locally on my machine locally (with a service account key I specifically generated from that service account for this experiment), the service cannot read the bucket as it should be. If, during the local run, I do add the roles/storage.objectViewer to that service account, the service can read the bucket (which is obviously expected).
I am confused because when the service runs in Cloud Run, it magically acquires the permissions to read that bucket, and I cannot figure out how.
Any advice?

Your service should run with another service account. Or, your local environment does not take into account your service account key file (Note that you can simply perform impersonation to avoid key generation)

Cloud run defaults to using the "compute engine default service account" PROJECT_NUMBER -compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com. Which has read permission on all buckets in the project, so most likely you set the SA wrong and it defaulted to that one.

As mentioned, by default Cloud Run service deployments uses the default compute engine service account which uses Basic Role Editor that gives read and write permission on multiple services within the project.
You can use specific service account for your cloud run service by editing Security tab in the console or if you are using gcloud cli, you can use the following command:
gcloud run services update SERVICE --service-account SERVICE_ACCOUNT

gcloud run deploy --image IMAGE_URL --service-account SERVICE_ACCOUNT

Also, take note of the serivce accounts identity that can be used in cloud run.
